# Getting first letter of word for non-English characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to display username first letter

I have this name like example

```
 $name = "Афанасий Никитин";
 echo $name[0];
```

it works with English characters only, when I use non-English character I get it like this  �

How to fix this issue  also this way Is the fastest way to get first letter is there any way or good alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is a multibyte string, meaning that one character can occupy more than one byte. You have to use multibyte functions to get at the charachter:

```
$name = "Афанасий Никитин";
echo mb_substr($name,0,1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

or in the newest PHP versions you could try:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php

Comment: @IncredibleHat Sorry about that, but I started mine before you commented. :-) It wasn't a difficult question. The suggestion by Andre Motta to use the correct header is valid. Also use sources in UTF8 and HTML5 or a proper UFT8 header in HTML.

Comment: I still vote for yours, because the actual issue is not solved by the other answer.

Comment: That's perfect I didn't know it might take more then one byte  Thank you for new info

Comment: @ KIKO Software   The header already has  UTF8 META    and it's not  the issue here   I can display non English words, but as KIKO explain I'm taking first  bit  while other language but take mote then one bit  not like English

Comment: Learning something new everyday huh!

Thanks for the great answer